# Maven builds are working, but junit is throwing a NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

Just added PowerMock to my projects pom files so I can start mocking some static methods. I've verified all the versions are up to date, this includes Juint, Javassit, and mockito. The one line that is causing this problem is this:

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

When that line is commented out, my code runs fine through Junit, with it Junit has a heart attack, but a maven build works perfectly.  Now I can get used to working with maven builds, but I would love the ability to debug my tests through Junit.

I have tried the following: cleaning eclipse, using maven installs/cleans/builds from both Terminal and Eclipse's UI, furiously pressing F5 while rocking myself in a dark corner for 2 hours. Any assistance on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the failure trace when I try to run as a junit test.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.CtMethod.hasAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.TestClassTransformer.removeTestAnnotationsForTestMethodsThatRunOnOtherClassLoader(TestClassTransformer.java:185)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.TestClassTransformer.transform(TestClassTransformer.java:198)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:145)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)


            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: you mention that you are using maven, so can you show us your pom.xml file?

Comment: I added answer, please try it, and let me know if it fixed your problem.

Comment: I added the part of my Parent pom file with its dependencies I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm using Raptor (I believe that's an in house version of Eclipse) which forces certain dependency version installs (even without a pom). Even though I only had the right versions in my pom files, Raptor was installing incompatible versions before hand, which took precedence. (at least thats what I believe was happening)

I had to do some forceful version control in my parent pom using dependency managers, and I seemed to have cleared up the issue. Though a few more problems followed with the libraries not having the correct methods. I ended up resolving those issues by finding versions of the dependencies (allowed by companies repository manager) that worked together (a lot of tinkering and seeing which versions would play nice). Because of the repository manager I was unable to download just the latest version of each dependency I needed.

If you are experiencing this problem make sure your versions are compatible, if you can get the newest version of the dependencies do that. If not, grab a beer, and start with the latest versions offered by your repository manager and start trying to find versions that work with each other.

Comment: Could you please share the details of what exactly you did? I'm facing the exact same problem with raptor.

Comment: I found the fix. I had to add
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ebay.raptor.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>RaptorKernel</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
     <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

The information you provided is not enough to find out what could be the problem. I would recommend you to run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

It will list you all the dependencies, that you have in your project.Try to find simillar dependencies with different versions.

**Another** possible solution: Do you have the correct Javassist version (3.18.2) in the classpath?

Comment: None of my dependencies have different versions. I'm using the Javassist version 3.4, would a newer version cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. I had to add

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ebay.raptor.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>RaptorKernel</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

RaptorKernel could be replaced by any artifact which is bringing in the javassist different(other than 3.18.2) dependency.